# Why this function return an (owned) value?

Tags: memory-management, vala, genie, ownership-semantics

the code
from: [Genie howto repeat a string N times as an string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370915/genie-howto-repeat-a-string-n-times-as-an-string-array/31372904)[Genie howto repeat a string N times as an string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370915/genie-howto-repeat-a-string-n-times-as-an-string-array/31372904)

```
def repeatwithsep (e: string, n: int, separator: string): string
    var elen = e.length;
    var slen = separator.length;
    var a = new StringBuilder.sized ((elen * n) + (slen * (n - 1)) + 1);
    for var i = 0 to (n - 1)
        if i != 0
            a.append_len (separator, slen)
        a.append_len (e, elen)
    return (owned) a.str
```

**var a** is a local variable,  when **a** goes out of scope, it will be destroyed.
why this function

**return (owned) a.str**

what is the difference between

return a.str

return (owned) a.str

what is the benefit of (owned)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return a.str` will make a copy of the string using `g_strdup`, because by default the function result and the StringBuilder will both own a separate copy of the string after the (implicit) assignment.

Since the StringBuilder stored in `a` will go out of scope and it's copy will thus never be used again this is not desireable / efficient in this case.

Hence the solution is to pass ownership of the string from `a.str` to the result of the function using the `(owned)` directive.

BTW: You can easily find this out by compiling both versions with `valac -C` and comparing the generated C code:

```
-       _tmp21_->str = NULL;
-       result = _tmp22_;
+       _tmp23_ = g_strdup (_tmp22_);
+       result = _tmp23_;
```

(In this comparison the left side was `return (owned) a.str` and the right side was `return a.str`)

PS: This is documented in the [ownership section of the Vala tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Ownership) and also the [corresponding part of the Genie tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Genie#Ownership_Transfer).

I would also recommend the [Reference Handling article](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ReferenceHandling).

Comment: As the jerk who wrote that snippet without explaining it, I can confirm that that is the reason for the `(owned)` ;)

Comment: if **(owned)**? The raw data will completely disappear.
according to my understanding, it is **unowned**.

Comment: @NaamFamas I don't understand you comment, could you please rephrase it?