# Has Vala memory leak when building shared library?

Tags: c, glib, vala

Will this Vala code memory leak when it built as shared library (.so)?

Vala:

```
namespace test {
    public static string info(string name){
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

Source code (`valac -C`)

```
gchar* test_info (const gchar* name) {
    gchar* result = NULL;
    const gchar* _tmp0_ = NULL;
    gchar* _tmp1_ = NULL;
    g_return_val_if_fail (name != NULL, NULL);
    _tmp0_ = name;
    _tmp1_ = g_strconcat ("Hello ", _tmp0_, NULL);
    result = _tmp1_;
    return result;
}
```

Compilation: `valac --library=test  -H test.h "test.vala" -X -fPIC -X -shared -o test.so`

I am surprised by no memory deallocation in `test_info`.

- Will `g_strconcat` store allocated memory in global variable (possible thread-local)?
- Will be memory leak if I call `test_info` from external programm miltiple times without deallocation?

I am sorry about this possible simple question, but I am new in Vala (my primary experience in area of Go, Python, C++ and etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will return an **owned** string, so the caller is responsible for the memory deallocation.

If you call this library function from vala the compiler will make sure that it is deallocated.

If you call it from `C` you should read the [GLib documentation for g_strconcat](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strconcat):

> Concatenates all of the given strings into one long string. The
>   returned string should be freed with g_free() when no longer needed.

I would recommend you to read:

- The [ownership section of the Vala tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Ownership)
- The [Reference Handling article](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ReferenceHandling)

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386774/why-this-function-return-an-owned-value) (which is about Genie, Valas "sister language" though).